# Surface plot with different number of points in x, y and z axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a `surface plot` with 549 points.
The `x axis` has `51` points and y-axis has `9` points. 
and the `z-axis` has 549 points. For example:

```
fig  = plt.figure()
X = list(xrange(0,51))
Y = list(xrange(0,9))
Z = list(xrange(0,459))

print len(X)
print len(Y)
print len(Z)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap=plt.cm.jet, cstride=1, rstride=1)
plt.savefig('graph-1' + '.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.2,dpi=100)
plt.clf()
```

And I try to plot it I get the following error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: two or more arrays have incompatible dimensions on axis 1.
```

How do we plot when we have different axis lengths?

The 3-tuple looks like this:

```
for a in range(0,len(X)):
 for b in range(0, len(Y)):
  for c in range(0, len(Z)):
    print (a,b,c)
```

Comment: if you have more `z` points than `x*y`, how can it plot those points?  each point you're plotting needs to be a tuple `(x,y,z)`.  If you just have a z value with no corresponding `x,y,` values matplotlib has no information about where the draw the z value.

Comment: It is something like this for (X1,Y1,Z1); (X1,Y2,Z2). I can get in the form of sublists and give the data.
Please check the edit.

Comment: `51*9=459`.  Also, the lists need to be equal length.  What happens when it reaches the end of Y (length 9).  (X10,?,Z10).  You'll need to create lists of equal length by repeating X and Y.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I forgot to give the correct Z dimension. How do I plot it now?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Andrey

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


def fun(x, y):
        return test[x][y]

global test
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = list(xrange(0,9))
y = list(xrange(0,51))
test = [[a for a in range(0, len(y)] for b in range(0, len(x))]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Ok, looking at this again, you want to plot 459 point, on a grid.  Using this loop:

```
for a in range(0,len(X)):
    for b in range(0, len(Y)):
        for c in range(0, len(Z)):
            print (a,b,c)
```

will give you many more than 459 points, it will give you `51*9*459` points.

try this:

```
import itertools
X2,Y2=zip(*list(itertools.product(X,Y)))
```

This will create all possible combinations of `x,y` then you should be able to plot `(X2,Y2,Z)`.  `len(X2)` and `len(Y2)` are both `459`

Comment: Here is the size of X2, Y2 and Z2 210681, 210681, 210681
and I get the following error:
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

Comment: No. I don't think that solves the problem. Since the above list only gives 2-tuple. We need t build a 3-tuple if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: it give two lists of length 459. those are your x and y lists.  You already have one list of length 459, your z values.  In order to plot those, you need a list of x points and a list of y points.  All three of these lists need to be the same length to plot them.  This function creates a grid of your x and y ranges.

Comment: When I try to plot it. I get the same error, that is, zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity.

Comment: do you have actual data for this? If the length of your z array is 210681, that means you are trying to plot more than 459 points.

Comment: The length of `Z` is 459. Yes, I do have the actual data.

Comment: ok, can you post the data, it will help instead of using ranges.

Comment: The data is exactly in the form of ranges.
Instead if we want we can use the rand function to get some `list data` of length 459

Comment: Ok.I got the answer and the mistake we made. @Andrey is correct.